# Plotting locations of a state in India in maps using R

Tags: r, plot, maps

I have a list of locations from Uttarakhand state in India. The dataset is like this

```
    address lat long
    Ajabpur 30.0431765  78.8255226
    UHC Ajabpur 30.0431765  78.8255226
    Asan Bag    30.5829083  77.7523608
    Ashtad  30.6865869  77.8453043
    Badripur    30.2843949  78.0656264
    Balawala    30.2661801  78.1062092
    Ballupur    30.3335862  78.0115041
    Barontha    30.066753   79.0192997
```

I wish to plot these points on the map of Uttarakhand using R. How do i accomplish it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several examples.

but here is one using `ggplot2` and `ggmap`. Look at the manual of ggmap and you will find many options.

```
data_table <- read.table(text="
add         lat         long
Ajabpur     30.0431765  78.8255226
UHCAjabpur  30.0431765  78.8255226
AsanBag    30.5829083  77.7523608
Ashtad      30.6865869  77.8453043
Badripur    30.2843949  78.0656264
Balawala    30.2661801  78.1062092
Ballupur    30.3335862  78.0115041
Barontha    30.066753   79.0192997",
    header = TRUE)

library(ggplot2)
library(ggmap)

map <- get_map(
location = c(78.825, 30.04),
source = "google", zoom = 15, maptype = "satellite"
)

ggmap(map) +
geom_point(data=data_table, aes(x = long, y = lat), alpha = .5, color="red")
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you @MLavoie, I used the googlevis function to plot. However I have another query, along with the data I've used here there's another set of data related to hospitals which fall in these locations, how do I find which hospital is under which block(The blocks are the one mentioned in the data above)? Another question is that is there any way I can show the maps and the blocks in the same map?

Comment: for each of your block you could create a buffer zone (polygon) and with the function over() from package sp you could determine under which block hospitals are located

Comment: can those buffer regions be created using lat and long values of the blocks? If yes, please help me with it

Comment: yes! but you need to turn your dataset into a spatial dataframe and  then use gbuffer (http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/rgeos/docs/gBuffer) which will turn into a spatial polygon dataframe. It's a bit complicated, and there is not enough space to explain in the comment section..but you can look on SO..if it's not enough maybe you could ask another question. We also need access to your hospital dataset.